# MySql: Extract products with identical options

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that would extract products that have identical option values assigned to them. Affected tables are:

```
products
| id |

rel_product_options
| product | option | value |
"option" is an id from "options" table
"value" is an option value id from "values" table (an option can have multiple values. eg. option "color" can have "red", "blue" etc.)
```

Every product has multiple option-value combinations ir "rel_product_options" table. Variations of the same product cannot have identical option-value pairs and that's why prior to changing any value on any option i need to check if the next value would no conflict with some other product. Let's assume

- product A (color: red, size: 10)
- product B (color: blue, size: 10)

Now if i try to change color of "product B" to "red" - i should be able to find in the database that options of "product A" would be identical and cancel the change. I hope the question is clear and honestly i don't even know where to start: sql is something of a mystery to me no matter how many times i use it ... I've started with something like the code below, but i think it is probably wrong on more levels than i can count to so any help is very appreciated.

```
# my thoughts
SELECT P1.*, PO1.*, PO2.* FROM products AS P1
# first select the product we want to extract all options from
# THIS ALREADY IS WRONG, because one of the options is ABOUT TO CHANGE, but this code assumes it has already done that
JOIN rel_product_options AS PO1 ON (PO1.product = P1.id AND PO1.product = 1)
# now join all other products that do not have identical option-value pairs
LEFT JOIN rel_product_options AS PO2 ON (PO1.product != PO2.product AND PO1.`option` = PO2.`option` AND PO1.value = PO2.value)
# and ... i'm lost ...
```

Comment: Are you trying to put a constraint to prevent inserting any identical values or just select products with identical values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but try something like this to find duplicate products of THIS_PRODUCT_ID. Note I am assuming that each row in `rel_product_options` is unique.

```
SELECT o2.product AS duplicateProduct 
FROM rel_product_options o
INNER JOIN rel_product_options o2 ON o.product <> o2.product 
    AND o.option = o2.option 
    AND o.value = o2.value
WHERE o.product = THIS_PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY o2.product
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM rel_product_options o3 
                   WHERE o3.product = THIS_PRODUCT_ID)
```

---

Edit: It looks like you are trying to put this in an `ON UPDATE` trigger for `rel_product_options`. This is a bit of a hack, but I suppose you could try something like the following. This is of course assuming that `OLD.product = NEW.product` otherwise all bets are off:

```
SELECT o2.product AS duplicateProduct 
FROM
(
    SELECT product, 
        CASE WHEN option = OLD.option AND value = OLD.value THEN NEW.option ELSE option END AS option, 
        CASE WHEN option = OLD.option AND value = OLD.value THEN NEW.value ELSE value END AS value
    FROM rel_product_options
    WHERE product = NEW.product
) o
INNER JOIN rel_product_options o2 ON o.product <> o2.product 
    AND o.option = o2.option 
    AND o.value = o2.value
GROUP BY o2.product
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM rel_product_options o3 
                   WHERE o3.product = NEW.product)
```

---

Edit 2: If you're running this from PHP, changing a parameter's value, you can try the following. This now assumes that (`product`, `option`) is unique, and the option *already exists, with a different value*. That is, you will be following up the query with an `UPDATE` to modify a row, not an `INSERT`.

```
SELECT o2.product AS duplicateProduct 
FROM
(
    SELECT product, 
        option, 
        CASE WHEN option = @option THEN @newValue ELSE value END AS value
    FROM rel_product_options
    WHERE product = @product
) o
INNER JOIN rel_product_options o2 ON o.product <> o2.product 
    AND o.option = o2.option 
    AND o.value = o2.value
GROUP BY o2.product
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM rel_product_options o3 
                   WHERE o3.product = @product)
```

There are three parameters in this query:

- `@product`: The product ID in question
- `@option`: The option you are changing
- `@newValue`: The new value you will change the option to

Comment: So far i'm getting an error "Unknown column 'database.o.product' in 'where clause')". This is mysql, maybe it does not understand "o.product" in a subselect? Trying to solve it.

Comment: Yep, if i hardcode THIS_PRODUCT_ID into subselect as well, it executes.

Comment: thanks - it works perfectly, but the problem now is that the duplicate does not yet exist, since the value of the specific option has not been changed yet. I'll try to modify this myself to select all non-affected option-values and then to join the affected option with a "soon-to-be" new value.

Comment: Yes you need to provide a value for THIS_PRODUCT_ID. Sorry it is just a placeholder.

Comment: I know it's a placeholder, but it was supposed to be in the second WHERE as well, because MySQL didn't know what "o" was in a subselect for some reason. The end should be: WHERE o3.product = THIS_PRODUCT_ID

Comment: Right. I could have also grouped by o.product to fix that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks again, but i'm unsuccessful with modifying this query to check the duplicates PRIOR to value change. Let's say i know that option 8 now has value 14, but it will soon have value 12. I need this query to replace option 8's value with 12 dynamically. I was trying to do modify an inner join like this: INNER JOIN rel_product_options AS o2 ON (o.product <> o2.product 
    AND o.option = o2.option
    AND o.value = o2.value
    AND o.option != 8) 
    OR (o.product <> o2.product 
    AND o.value = 12
    AND o.option = 8) but it doesn't work. I'm affraid my sql understanding is terrible :(

Comment: Ok, now I understand that you're trying to do the select in a trigger *before* a row changes. So try my edit.

Comment: Again, thank you. Actually i just need a query: NOT using any triggers - just querying from php before executing an UPDATE. Tried creating a trigger though, but got an error that i can't return a result set from it. maybe it's another MySQL specific thing ... If it were possible to modify your first query - that one would be perfect

Comment: Ok, try my new update. You cannot *return* a result set from a trigger, that's not what they are for; you would instead throw an exception from the trigger which would cause the `UPDATE` to fail and the error to be sent back to the calling PHP code. You would wrap the query in an `IF EXISTS()` and do something (probably just throw the exception).

Comment: I would have never thought of this ... Thanks for all your help - as far as initial testing goes, i can say it works perfectly!